# Why are there so many files in directory /etc/share?

Tags: linux, emacs

Why are emacs related files still in /usr/share/emacs even after I uninstall emacs? Can I delete files in /usr/share/emacs?

```
[root@home share]# rpm -qa | grep emacs
[root@home share]#
[root@home share]# ls emacs/
21.4  site-lisp
[root@home share]# pwd
/usr/share
```

I think there are too many files in /usr/share directory, which files and directories can I delete?

```
[root@home usr]# ls
bin  etc  games  include  kerberos  lib  libexec  local  man  sbin  share  src  tmp  X11R6
[root@home usr]# find share/ | wc -l
39786
[root@home usr]# ls share/
aclocal               autoconf      cups       et         GeoIP              groff    libtool     misc       rhgb      swat          themes
aclocal-1.9           autoconf2.6x  cvs        eula       gettext            gtk-2.0  locale      muttprint  rrdtool   t1lib         vim
anaconda              automake-1.9  dbus-1     file       ghostscript        hal      logwatch    mysql      samba     tabset        X11
anthy                 avahi         denyhosts  firstboot  git-core           hwdata   lua         ntop       screen    tcl8.4        xemacs
application-registry  awk           dict       fonts      gnome-2.0          i18n     magic       openldap   sgml      terminfo      xml
applications          bogofilter    doc        games      gnome-mount        icons    magic.mime  pear       snmp      texinfo       xsessions
apps                  clamav        dstat      GConf      gnome-screensaver  info     man         php        spamdyke  texmf         yum-cli
asciidoc              cmake         emacs      gdb        gnupg              irssi    mime        pixmaps    ss        texmf-config  zoneinfo
authconfig            cracklib      empty      gdm        graphviz           lftp     mime-info   pkgconfig  swamp     texmf-var     zsh
[root@home usr]# ls share/autoconf
autoconf  Autom4te  autom4te.cfg  autoscan  autotest  INSTALL  m4sugar
[root@home usr]# ls share/autoconf/autoscan/
autoscan.list
```

Comment: If your Linux distro provides a package manager leave alone that stuff, it should be managed automatically by it. Besides, it's off topic here.

Comment: How many files do you think is too many in `/usr/share`? Why?

Comment: dude,where should be this topic? maybe you can help me to move my topic to superuser:)

Comment: I'd send that to [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), personally. (And I'm interested so know the answer.)

Comment: The /usr/share/emacs directory is most probably a leftover from "manual" (as opposed to package management) installation of emacs stuff. Look at how old that stuff in there (if any) is, and delete that. Leave the rest alone!

Answer (score 0):

These files can belong to other packages, which also provide some emacs modes. You can check from which RPM package this file by using rpm command, e.g.:

> rpm -qf /usr/share/emacs/path/to/file

It's a bad idea to delete any system files manually. 
I would suggest to use your package manager for that.